# "type mismatch expecting AutoInc actual LongWord" on FDQuery (Delphi XE6)

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe6, firedac

We use Delphi XE6 the component with error is a TFDQuery in MySQL 4.1.

When I try to open the Query using a group the FDQuery show:

> type mismatch expecting AutoInc actual LongWord

In the Field Editor the field is correct,it shows `AutoInc` but the error always appears, if I remove the `group by` on query the error stop but the results is wrong and when I remove all fields of Field Editor and try again, work correctly.

I tried to insert a field manually on Field Editor as an `Integer` field, but it didn't work either.

The field with error (`NUMBOLE`) in my table is an `Integer` field, `AutoInc` (primary key from tabbolvenda)

```
  FDQuery1.Close;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('select');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('b.NUMVENDA,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('a.DATAVENDA,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('b.NUMBOLE,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('b.PARCELAS,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('a.CODCLIENTE,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('a.NOMECLIENTE,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('b.DATAVTO,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('a.MONTANTE,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('b.DATAPTO,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('if(b.EMABERTO = ''True'', ''Sim'',''Não'') as EMABERTO,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('a.CUSTOVENDA,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('a.LUCROVENDA,');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('a.COMISSAO');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('from tabvendas a inner join tabbolvenda b');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('on a.NUMVENDA = b.NUMVENDA');
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('group by b.NUMVENDA order by b.NUMVENDA'); <--- if I remove this group by it works
  FDQuery1.Open;
```

Is there any property on FDQuery that it makes this error disappear? When my project use to be on Delphi 6 with Zeos Query, the same `select` doesn't show any error message. It happens only on FDQuery.

Comment: MySQL changes an auto-inc column data type when it is in SELECT list with and without GROUP BY. Do you created persistent fields when query was with GROUP BY ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of fields in select have to be equal the number of fields in group by if you not use aggregate functions. 
From [docs](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php):

```
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n, 
       aggregate_function (aggregate_expression)
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
GROUP BY expression1, expression2, ... expression_n;
```

where `expression1, expression2, ... expression_n` - 
Expressions that are not encapsulated within an aggregate function and must be included in the `GROUP BY` Clause at the end of the SQL statement.

Comment: This is correct for ANSI SQL and may be some other DB's. MySQL allows to include into SELECT list non-aggregated columns: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html